# String Reference = null i dont understand

Tags: c#

pretty simple setup.

```
public ObservableCollection<ParentNode> CreateTreeViewCollection(string ClassName)
{
    EnumerateFullData AllData = new EnumerateFullData() { ClassName = ClassName.Clone() };
}

public class EnumerateFullData
{
    public Object ClassName { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyData> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

when the object is created the `ClassName` value is `null` even tho it has a value before the class I created.
Once the class has completed and the debugger comes back to the original class, the value is there again.
Im thinking this has to do with instance spawning, can anyone advise how I pass this reference into the newly created class?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get that. But: You are using an object initializer here. So When the EnumerateFullData object is created, the ClassName property was not set (yet). Only after the assignment is executed the value is set. It is equivalent to writing:

EnumerateFullData AllData = new EnumerateFullData();
AllData = ClassName.Clone();

Comment: In the "CreateTreeViewCollection(string ClassName)" change "ClassName" to "className"; and "ClassName = ClassName.Clone()" change for "ClassName = className.Clone()". Do not tease the compiler...

Comment: You can omit the brackets for the constructor call if you are using an object initializer.

Comment: read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.clone(v=vs.110).aspx, especially the line that says "Because the Clone method simply returns the existing string instance, there is little reason to call it directly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassName` value gets assigned after the object is created since use are using class initializer. If you want to assign the value during object creation use a constructor. Also, you don't need to use `ClassName.Clone()` if you change the property to string type as string is immutable. Following code should work:

```
public ObservableCollection<ParentNode> CreateTreeViewCollection(string ClassName)
{
    EnumerateFullData AllData = new EnumerateFullData(ClassName);
}

public class EnumerateFullData
{
    public EnumerateFullData (string className)
    { 
        ClassName  = className;
    }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyData> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was the one that worked, all others failed. since i need to use the variable in my constructor this was the best option. thank you +1 and marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `ClassName` that is `EnumerateFullData`'s property and `ClassName` that is 
`CreateTreeViewCollection`'s argument; so you're *trying to clone null*. Change your code for

```
  // Let argument be in the camel case, "className" not "ClassName"
  public ObservableCollection<ParentNode> CreateTreeViewCollection(string className)
  {
    // property "ClassName" is a clone of argument "className"
    EnumerateFullData AllData = 
      new EnumerateFullData() { ClassName = className.Clone() };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using object initializer. They are just syntactic sugar. writing

```
EnumerateFullData AllData = new EnumerateFullData() { ClassName = ClassName.Clone() };
```

is actually this:

```
var temp = new EnumerateFullData();
temp.ClassName = ClassName.Clone();
EnumerateFullData AllData = temp;
```

First you create your class and only after that you set the `ClassName` Property.
You can do that in a single like because the compiler does that for you.
It means that when the `EnumerateFullData` instance is created the `ClassName` is really null.